# TextViews recycle their positions and title when scrolling, Glide Gallery

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am trying to use the Glide Image Library to load images in a gridview an using REccycler View. However, I wanted the to have a title TextView beneath each image.

I have set a custom layout for this and tried to load the TextView in the onBindViewHolder. This works but on scrolling, the positions are recycled, and the TextViews Titles are changed, making a mess of it.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
  Image image = images.get(position);

//        // setup Glide request without the into() method
//        DrawableRequestBuilder<String> thumbnailRequest = Glide
//                .with(mContext)
//                .load(image.getMedium());

    // pass the request as a a parameter to the thumbnail request
    Glide.with(mContext).load(image.getMedium())
            .thumbnail(0.3f)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(holder.thumbnail);


     titleText.setText(image.getName());

}
```

How do I fix this dear developers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the titleText is not stored in the ViewHolder.

Save it inside your holder object and use:

```
holder.titleText.setText(image.getName());
```

This will change the TextView accordingly as the holder changes. Else it will be a mess as the holders are recycled.

something like:

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
TextView titleText;
ImageView thumbnail;
.
.
.



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
Image image = images.get(position);


Glide.with(mContext).load(image.getMedium())
        .thumbnail(0.3f)
        .crossFade()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .into(holder.thumbnail);


 holder.titleText.setText(image.getName());

}
}
```

Comment: please accept as answered if it solves your question :) if not tell me so that i can try to help